# ASP.NET / MySQL SQLDataSource StoredProcedure

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

re all,

I'm using a stored procedure as InsertCommand for an ASP.NET SQLDataSource:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource 
    ID="_sdsData" 
    runat="server" 
    OnInserted="_sdsData_Inserted"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:_db %>"
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:_db.ProviderName %>" 
    InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure"
    InsertCommand="create_module">
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="_type" ControlID="_fvDataR$_ddlType" Type="String" PropertyName="SelectedItem.Value" />
        <asp:SessionParameter Name="_id" SessionField="USER_ID" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="_code" Direction="Output" Type="String" />
    </InsertParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Everything works now but I found that mispelling the stored procedure name in `InsertCommand`**doesn't** lead to an error. The only abnormal behaviour in this case was an empty value as return parameter `_code`.

Is there a way to find if the stored procedure call have been completed successfully ?

Best regards,
 Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re all,

forget my question it only need to check for an exception in the event handler:

```
protected void _sdsData_Inserted(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
    if( e.Exception!=null)
        // Handle the exception
}
```